# How does one compute a group modulo a torsion group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let's say I have some group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $H$ is a torsion group (i.e. $\forall h \in H$, $h$ has finite order. How do I compute the factor group $\frac{G}{H}$? What effect does the order of each torsion element have on it?

Comment: First, the factor $\;G/H\;$ has meaning only if $\;H\;$ is a subgroup of $\;G\;$ and **also** if it is a *normal subgroup* . What do you **really** try to ask here?

Comment: I'm solving a problem in Hatcher where I'm trying to find a homology group but I'm stuck at figuring out how to factor out my image from my kernel of my boundary functions. Thus I was trying to ask in more general terms how this sort of scenario would go so I could solve my problem. So indeed $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ok, then, for any $\;x\in G\;$, if $\;|xH|=n\;$ , then $$(xH)^n=x^nH=H\iff x^n\in H$$ If $\;H\;$ is the subgroup of **all** the torsion elements of $\;G\;$ (for example, if $\;G\;$ is abelian as it happens in homology groups), then the above shows the group $\;G/H\;$ is torsion free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your groups are most likely abelian and finitely generated, you can factor $G$ into the direct sum of its torsion group and a free group.  This reduces any such problem to a problem about *finite* abelian groups.